# Elastic search java client. Initialisation of TransportClient takes long time

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-jest

Why does default initialisation of `TransportClient()` for elasticsearch takes much more time then initialisation of jest client?

Code for TransportClient:

```
private static Client client = new TransportClient()
        .addTransportAddress(
                new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9200)
        );
```

Code for jest client:

```
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig.Builder("http://localhost:9200")
                                .multiThreaded(true)
                                .build());
client = factory.getObject();
```

Jest client is light. However I need some extended functionality that have elasticsearch java client, but doesn't have jest client.

Is it possible to decrease time of initialisation for TransportClient by configuration? Why does it take too much time?

P.S. Initialisation of TransportClient takes approximately 6+ sec for me on Mac 16 GB of RAM.

Please, not that I initialise clients just once in code (using static and/or thread safe singleton)

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html, http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html I think you need to run native Java ES client on port 9300.

Comment: Thank you. It allowed me to decrease time up to ~2 secs for initialisation for localhost. However it takes still more then jest client. Is it possible to improve it?

Comment: May I ask what is the extended functionality you are missing on Jest (just curious)?

Comment: Sure. Each document indexed and associated with an id and a type. I need to do a massive select (selecting all documents from one index). I need to have opportunity to get type of returned document. There is a class in jest client that called Hit. I have ability to get source of the returned document, but do not have an ability to get type. It's possible to return response (list of documents in my case) as json string. But i need to parse it by myself to retrieve index, type - to extend Hit class. However ES java client has SearchHit interface that contain method getType() - one that i need